# passing 2d char array and assigning value

Tags: c++, char

I have a `char` array declared as

```
char userName[20][35];
```

I think that should be 20 buffers of 35 chars each.

So now I try and send it to a function:

```
readNames(userName[20][35])
{


}
```

I tried several different ways, is that the correct way to pass the array?  Now I need to assign a value I read out of user input.

```
strcpy(userName[numberOfUsers] , userInput);
```

So two parts, did I send the array to the function ok?  And how how do I do the `strcpy`?  It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it several ways. For safety, you should add a size limit parameter so the callee (your function) knows how large the dominant dimension is:

```
void readNames(char names[][35], size_t n)
{
    // your code here using names[0] through names[n-1]
}
```

and called as:

```
char names[20][35];
readNames(names, sizeof(names)/sizeof(*names));
```

Similarly, this also works (and in fact is synonymous with the above):

```
void readNames(char (*names)[35], size_t n)
{
    // your code here using names[0] through names[n-1]
}
```

Both work, but there is a better way with C++ if you truly want to stick to C-style arrays. (shown later).

Lastly, this:

```
strcpy(userName[numberOfUsers] , userInput);
```

is correct syntax. Just make sure to remember that `numberOfUsers` cannot exceed **or meet** the boundary of the array (the `size_t n` you pass from the caller in the above samples). The addressing is just like C, zero based up to `(n-1)`.

---

**Fixed Array Size Determination with Template Deduction**

A *much* more robust mechanism for doing this with C++ involves using template deduction to ensure the function knows the dimensions. It is considerably more flexible, as it can be used with different array declarations:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N, size_t M>
void readNames(char (&names)[N][M])
{
    // use names[0]... names[N-1], where
    // each is a char [0..M-1] buffer.

    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    char shortnames[20][30];
    readNames(shortnames);

    char longnames[50][100];
    readNames(longnames);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
void readNames(char (&)[N][M]) [N = 20, M = 30]
void readNames(char (&)[N][M]) [N = 50, M = 100]
```

---

**How about that Standard Library, Eh?**

If you really want to do the above, knock yourself out, but honestly, we're a decade-plus deep into the new millennium. Stop using technology from the 80's and 90's:

```
std::vector<std::string> readNames()
{
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    while (some-condition)
    {
        // get name here
        std::string name;

        //add to result
        res.push_back(name);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> names = readNames();
```

Comment: Beat me to writing this up. Templates are definitely a more elegant and safe way to go here. I might add a third possibility however, if you want to avoid needing to know any of the sizing at compile time you can also have your function signature be more like `void readNames(char *names, unsigned width, unsigned height);` and make a macro or function such as `#define GET_INDEX(x,y) ((y)*width+(x))` and maybe an assert to ensure you're not reading/writing past the end of the array.

Comment: Hey THANK YOU for the detailed help here!  I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you chose is something of a function prototype, not a call.  Each is written differently.

To call readnames with that array:

```
readNames (userName);
```

To declare the function:

```
void readNames (char names[20][35])
{
  ...  manipulate names here ...
}
```

Change `void` to another type if the function returns a value.

Comment: It is also noteworthy that `char names[20][35]` in a parameter is really no different than `char names[100][35]` because both decay to `char(*)[35]`.

Comment: @0x499602D2:  If the low order indexes don't match, then all the access to individual elements will be misplaced from the point of view of the actual parameter.  Also, buffer overrun errors are more likely if the prototype is bigger than the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getinput(char names[][10], int s)
{
int j;
cout << "enter value ";
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
    j = 0;
    while (**condition**)\\what will be here,this condition is not working
    {
        cin >> names[i][j];
        j++;

    }
}
}
```